# Always redirecting to https without www

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, cpanel, whmcs

I have a website and have recently installed an SSL certificate. I want all links to the site to always redirect to the secure site without www, as I have made the SSL applicable to non-www.

Furthermore, I have WHMCS in the backend and want to redirect the `example.com/whmcs` 
page to `example.com/client-portal` as I have a third party plugin that links with whmcs.

What should I insert in my `.htaccess` file and in what folders should I insert the file? Can I specify everything from root and if this is the case, how do I force WHMCS to be happy with this?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

#### Edit

The good news is that I have solved the first part of the problem. All URLs now redirect to the non-www https website. The code that solved this issue was supplied by @John Conde - thanks John!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

My next goal is to have `example.com/whmcs` redirect to `example.com/client-portal`.

...but without redirecting `example.com/whmcs/admin` to `example.com/client-portal/admin`. In other words, `/whmcs/admin` should not redirect.

I have tried the following solution but without success. I'll appreciate it if you guys can help.

```
RewriteCond !^example\.com\/whmcs\/admin
RewriteCond ^example\.com\/whmcs$
RewriteRule https://example.com/client-portal [R=301,L]
```

My intention was that this causes `/whmcs` to redirect but not for `/whmcs/admin` to redirect.

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: 1. Do servers remember permanent redirects or do only browsers remember them? 2. Why does WHMCS not redirect to https if there is a redirect set up in CPanel? I did not see any htaccess file in my WHMCS root directory. 3. Why does some people put NC agent rewrite conditions? This does not seem necessary. 4. How do I know what will be in variables, e.g. S1? 5. Is %1 also some sort of variable? 6. Does the request URI variable hold the site URL with or without (or both) www?

Comment: I have tried a couple of things. My latest try was to use : RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC] RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: The problem I had here (I think it was this one) was that when I tried to access WHMCS it redirected to my home page.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would encompass your goal completely, but this would turn http www mode into https non-www mode:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then to redirect the whmcs to a new url, you can probably use a simple 301:
    `Redirect 301 /whmcs /client-portal`

These would both go into the root of your app, or optionally at the place where an A record is picked up.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried to employ it but it lacks one final thing. I only want /whmcs to be redirected to /client-portal and not /whmcs/admin. I have tried this code but it redirects /whmcs/admin to /client-portal/admin which does not exist.

Comment: Ah i see. Does the 301 work if you point /whmcs/admin to /client-portal? Also is there a htaccess inside the /whmcs or /whmcs/admin folder? Maybe just placing it differently/deeper will help to clean off that /admin

Comment: Yes, the 301 works but it ends up getting a url that is not available on the site. I don't see the logic in placing it deeper since if it goes into the /whmcs directory and finds the .htaccess file there it will redirect to /client-portal. This will also be the case for /whmcs/admin. Regarding your other question, no, I have removed all .htaccess files in subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

You could also take the approach of multiple rewrite rules.   Replace `example.com` with your actual domain name.

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# HTTPS is off!
# Redirect to the secure canonical URL
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
# Host name is not correct!
# (maybe it has a www?)
# Redirect to the secure canonical URL
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

As for the `succeedonline.co.za/whmcs` redirect, you can use a single simple rewrite rule for that:

```
RewriteRule ^whmcs$ https://example.com/client-portal [L,R=301]
```

The `^` means "starts with" and the `$` means "ends with", so that redirect will only get triggered when the URL is *exactly* `succeedonline.co.za/whmcs` and not when it is `succeedonline.co.za/whmcs/admin`.

Comment: I wonder whether the 2nd `RewriteRule` is necessary? Since the SSL cert is only valid for the bare domain, wouldn't the user be hit by an invalid cert warning first if they tried to access `https://www.example.com`?

Comment: I buy wildcard certs that cover multiple domain names, so I use such a rule.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that it does not yet redirect the non-www site under the HTTPS protocol. It does however work fine under the HTTP protocol. Here is an extract of my complete `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#RewriteCond !^example\.com\/clients\/bestuur
#RewriteCond ^example\.com\/clients$
#RewriteRule https://example.com/client-portal [R=301,L]
```